# Scale thread count by scaling factor

Tags: jmeter

How would I do multiply two constants or variables .

I have a number of Thread groups in a Jmeter test each with a variable number of threads.  I would like to multiple each threads Thread group by a constant factor , so I could run tests with different percentage of threads . 
I have tried defining a `scale` factor as `${__P{scale,1}}` so that I could multiply a constant thread count with the `scale` as `100 * ${__P{scale,1}}` , but Jmeter doesn't seem to recognize that.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't, you need to wrap your expression into i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy).

Example syntax:

```
${__groovy(100 * org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("scale"\, 1),)}
```

More information:

- [JMeterUtils JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/util/JMeterUtils.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)